# How to work with Table joins and Inline View

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Can anyone help me to understand this SQL query; I don't understand the concept behind it:

```
SELECT
    t2.*,
    (
        SELECT SUM (salary)
        FROM (
            SELECT
            tb1.*, 
            ROWNUM AS rnk
            FROM ( 
                SELECT *
                FROM employees e
                ORDER BY E.DEPARTMENT_ID, E.EMPLOYEE_ID
            ) tb1
        ) tb2
        WHERE   tb2.DEPARTMENT_ID = t2.DEPARTMENT_ID AND tb2.rnk <= t2.rnk
    ) dept_salary
FROM (
    SELECT   
        t1.*, 
        ROWNUM AS rnk
    FROM (  
        SELECT   
            e.employee_id,
            e.first_name,
            e.department_id,
            e.salary
        FROM employees e
        ORDER BY   E.DEPARTMENT_ID, E.EMPLOYEE_ID
    ) t1
) t2
```

Comment: If you can tell how much you have understood from this, we can help you further.

Comment: Visit this link http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/nested-subqueries.php

Comment: i am confuse after from keyword new subquery what kind of join that was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different type of SubQuery.

1. Scalar Sub Query : Query that is totally independent from the main query.

   select empno, 
          (select count(*) from emp) total_emp
   from emp

here the subquery is totally independent of the main query.

2. Corelated Sub Query: The sub query reffers to the main query.

   select empno, 
          (select deptname 
           from dept d 
           where e.deptno = d.deptno) deptname
   from emp e
3. Inline view :A sub query that is used as a table or view in a SQL

   select *
   from (select empno, deptname
         from emp e, dept d 
          where e.deptno = d.deptno)
   where sal > 100

From your query:

```
SELECT
    t2.*,
    (
        SELECT SUM (salary)  -- start Corelated Sub Query
        FROM (
            SELECT
            tb1.*, 
            ROWNUM AS rnk
            FROM ( 
                SELECT *  -- start Scalar Sub Query
                FROM employees e
                ORDER BY E.DEPARTMENT_ID, E.EMPLOYEE_ID -- end Scalar Sub Query
            ) tb1 
        ) tb2
        WHERE   tb2.DEPARTMENT_ID = t2.DEPARTMENT_ID AND tb2.rnk <= t2.rnk -- end Corelated Sub Query
    ) dept_salary
FROM (
    SELECT   -- start inline view
        t1.*, 
        ROWNUM AS rnk
    FROM (  
        SELECT   
            e.employee_id,
            e.first_name,
            e.department_id,
            e.salary
        FROM employees e
        ORDER BY   E.DEPARTMENT_ID, E.EMPLOYEE_ID
    ) t1
) t2  -- end inline view
```

NB:Now you can find out sub query within sub query and inline view within inline view in your question.